# Обьясните почему getFollowRedirects() класса HttpURLConnection всегда true?

Tags: java, redirect

Необходимо проверить есть ли редирект на ссылке, пробую использовать `getFollowRedirects()` но он всегда показывает `true`. в документации написано что

> Returns:
>       true if HTTP redirects should be automatically followed, false if not.

даже если подставляю заведомо мне известную ссылку без редиректов, тоже `true`

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://google.com").openConnection();

    if (httpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects()){
        System.out.println("redirect");
    }else{
        System.out.println("noredirect");
    }

  // sout: true
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем этот метод, в каких случаях он будет `false` если можно примером кода

Answer (score 1):

`true` по умолчанию. Смотрите все методы. Например, есть такой метод

```
httpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(boolean set)
```

Этот метод нужен для управления соединением - разрешения/запрета на перенаправление.